# React Native Stack Navigation "Home Screen Doesn't Exist"

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication, react-native-navigation

I am using Firebase authentication with react native to store users. When I login or register i get an error asking if i have a screen named "HomeScreen" as shown in the last code block. I believe my "user ?" line in the first code block is returning null everytime and is therefore not hitting hte home screen. Does naybody know a solution for this?

Thanks in advance.

## **App.js**

```
export default function App() {

  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true)
  const [user, setUser] = useState(null)

  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator>
        { user ? (
          <Stack.Screen name="HomeScreen" component={HomeScreen} >
            {(props) => <HomeScreen {...props} extraData={user} />}
          </Stack.Screen>
        ) : (
          <>
            <Stack.Screen name="Login" component={LoginScreen} />
            <Stack.Screen name="Registration" component={RegistrationScreen} />
          </>
        )}
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

## **LoginScreen.js**

```
const onLoginPress = () => {
    firebase
      .auth()
      .signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
      .then((response) => {
        const uid = response.user.uid
        const usersRef = firebase.firestore().collection('users')
        usersRef
          .doc(uid)
          .get()
          .then((firestoreDocument) => {
            if (!firestoreDocument.exists) {
              alert('User does not exist anymore.')
              return
            }
            const user = firestoreDocument.data()
            navigation.navigate('HomeScreen', { user })
          })
          .catch((error) => {
            alert(error)
          })
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        alert(error)
      })
  }
```

## **RegistrationScreen.js**

```
  const onRegisterPress = () => {
    if (password !== confirmPassword) {
      alert("Passwords don't match.")
      return
    }
    firebase
      .auth()
      .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
      .then((response) => {
        const uid = response.user.uid
        const data = {
          id: uid,
          email,
          fullName,
        }
        const usersRef = firebase.firestore().collection('users')
        usersRef
          .doc(uid)
          .set(data)
          .then(() => {
            navigation.navigate('HomeScreen', { user: data })
          })
          .catch((error) => {
            alert(error)
          })
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        alert(error)
      })
  }
```

## **HomeScreen.js**

````
export default function HomeScreen(props) {
    return (
        <View>
            <Text>Home Screen</Text>
        </View>
    )
}```





# **The Error**
````

The action 'NAVIGATE' with payload {"name":"HomeScreen","params":{"user":{"email":"altaafjahan15@gmail.com","id":"GTyOXdSOglhpAlthv6yGn0KeMgq1","fullName":"altaaf jahankeer "}}} was not handled by any navigator.

Do you have a screen named 'HomeScreen'?

If you're trying to navigate to a screen in a nested navigator, see https://reactnavigation.org/docs/nesting-navigators#navigating-to-a-screen-in-a-nested-navigator.

at node_modules@react-navigation\core\src\BaseNavigationContainer.tsx:null in defaultOnUnhandledAction
at node_modules@react-navigation\core\src\useNavigationHelpers.tsx:null in dispatch
at node_modules@react-navigation\core\src\useNavigationCache.tsx:null in withStack$argument_0
at node_modules@react-navigation\core\src\useNavigationCache.tsx:null in withStack
at src\screens\LoginScreen\LoginScreen.js:null in usersRef.doc.get.then$argument_0
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\Timers\JSTimers.js:null in _allocateCallback$argument_0
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\Timers\JSTimers.js:null in _callTimer

```
I tried removing the "users ?" line in the first code block entirely and it worked. Seems like my users arent being passed.
```

Answer (score 1):

I didn't see where you set the user data using **setUser**, anyway, you need to use state management like redux or context for global variable like user.

below code is for passing data between the screen, and it's not meant to be global state management and you can't access it using **"user ?"** only

```
navigation.navigate('HomeScreen', { user: data })
```